# How can I construct polynomials with "small" coefficients generating a prime "late"?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with degree $5$, integer coefficients and positive leading coefficient. Let $M$ be the maximum of the absolute values of the coefficients. Assume the smallest non-negative integer $n$ such that $f(n)$ is prime is greater than $10\ 000$, but that such an $n$ exist.

> - Can I construct polynomials with the desired property and "small" $M$ ?
> - Can the smallest possible $M$ be determined efficiently ?

Idea : Construct an irreducible polynomial such that the $\gcd$ of its values is $1$. This should generate at least one prime due to the Bunyakovsky-conjecture. The problem is to avoid an "earlier" prime.

Motivation : Constructing "hard cases" for the bunyakovsky conjecture.

Comment: Primes are plentiful; it's really, *really*, ***really*** hard for a relatively slow growing sequence like a polynomial to miss the primes so often.

Comment: @Hurkyl Do you have a guess how large $M$ must be ?

Comment: $M=10^6+1$ works with $f=X^5-(10^6+1)X^4+2$

Comment: @Mastrem $n=0$ is allowed as well, but I understand the point. If the polynomial is negative upto a high limit, we have of course a good chance for a "late" prime.

Comment: @Peter When a first prime occurs in $x^5+3x^4+3x^2+1$?

Comment: @Shalom $12$ is the smallest $x$ giving a prime.

Comment: @Mastrem But $f(0)=2$ is prime.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Yes, my mistake. I'll delete the comment shortly? EDIT: It's better not to delete it, since that would make that the two replies unclear

Comment: I have started a computer search. With $M=5$, I found that the first prime value of $-4-5 x+4 x^2+4 x^3-5 x^4+5 x^5$ appears at $x = 205$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Not bad, way larger than the coefficients.But I think Hurkyl is right, $10^6$ will only work if the polynomial gets greater than $1$ very late.

Comment: For what is worth, with $M=8$ the record is $6-3 x-6 x^2+7 x^3+5 x^4+6 x^5$. The first prime value comes at $x = 827$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Thank you, did you check all polynomials or just random polynomials and this was the record-holder ?

Comment: Since $10^6$ is probably too difficult , unless the polynomial gets large "very late" ,  I reduced to $10\ 000$

Comment: @Peter: My first back-of-the-envelope estimate suggests something like $M=10^{600}$ if you want the first $10^6$ values not to be prime. However, I have not checked how plausible by estimations are with values of this magnitude. I am modeling this as the odds that a "random" collection of $10^6$ numbers of size similar to the values of the polynomial is entirely composite. I am, however, counting the negative primes too. As Mastrem noted, if you are allowing $f$ to take negative prime values, you can reduce this by picking functions that are mostly negative.

Comment: With the problem changed to the first $10^4$ values, the estimate I was making drops to $M= 10^{18}$. But I *know* this time I'm outside the domain where my estimates are good, because the size of $x^5$ is no longer negligible as compared to the size of $M$.

Comment: @Hurkyl Does the question become more interesting , if I replace $f(n)$ by $|f(n)|$ ?

Comment: Julian's polynomial also remains valid if we replace $f(n)$ by $|f(n)|$. Moreover, it is positive for all non-negative $n$.

Comment: I checked all of them (if my program is correct). Now I am doing the calculation with $M=10$ and $f(0)$ even. At this moment the record holder is $-10-10 x-7 x^2+9 x^3+2 x^4+x^5$; the first prime appears at $x=1000$.

Comment: If we do not count negative primes, then $f(x)=7x^5 - 4x^4 - 5x^3 + 3x - 6$ is best with $M=8$, the first prime appearing at $1495$

Comment: The current best polynomial (even if negative primes count) is $$5x^5 - 11x^4 - 5x^3 + 10x - 9$$ with first prime occuring at $1990$ followed by $$4x^5 + 9x^4 + 10x^2 + 6x + 6$$ with first prime occuring at $1945$ and non-negative coefficients.

Comment: New record with $M=10$ (although I looked at $M=12$) : $$9x^5 - 8x^4 - x^3 + 3x^2 - 8x - 10$$ First prime occuring at $2337$ , possible negative primes considered.

Comment: If we consider negative primes, $2337$ is the optimum for $M=12$ and for $M=8$ the optimum is $827$ as already found out by Julian.

Comment: With $M=14$, the best polynomial is $$11x^5 - 4x^4 + 14x^3 + 11x^2 - 7x - 10$$ with first prime occuring at $3129$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by generalizing the notation a little ($d$ and $B$ will be positive integers):

- $H(P)$ will denote the [height of a polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Height_of_a_polynomial) (maximum of absolute values of its coefficients).
- $S_d(B)$ will denote the set of polynomials $P(x)$ of degree $d$ with integer coefficients for which:

  - $|P(k)|$ is prime for some positive integer $k$ but
  - $|P(k)|$ is not prime for $0\leq k\leq B$.
- Finally, define $M_d(B)=\min\limits_{P\in S_d(B)} H(P)$

In this notation, the original question was asking for $M_5(10^6)$ and the simplified version is looking for $M_5(10^4)$.

Note that the definition of $M_d(B)$ relies on $S_d(B)$ being non-empty; a property that is not as obvious as it may seem (or I might have missed the easy proof of it). Since we are only going to focus on a few specific cases, we can overlook this as a technical detail.

Using computer-assisted search, I found the polynomial $$P_5(x)=39x^5 + 6x^4 + 21x^3 - 44x^2 + 47x + 15$$ which doesn't produce a prime until $x=13076$ and thus belongs to $S_5(10^4)$. This implies $M_5(10^4)\leq 47$. Note that the search was not exhaustive, so the bound is not necessarily the optimal one.

As expected, if we let the degree increase, the coefficients of the polynomial can be lowered: For example, another search found $$P_6(x)=25x^6 + 24x^5 + 11x^4 + 10x^3 + 25x^2 - 4x + 14$$ which is non-prime until $x=10905$, so $M_6(10^4)\leq 25$ (again, the search was non-exhaustive, thus the *in*equality).

On the other hand, going down to degree $4$ yields polynomial $$P_4(x)=11x^4 - 146x^3 - 99x^2 + 19x + 105$$ which isn't prime until $x=10774$. Thus, $M_4(10^4)\leq 146$.